# Ionic Instagram plugin "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined"

Tags: android, plugins, ionic-framework, instagram, ngcordova

I'm using Ionic, and this error happens on android when I try to share picture with Instagram plugin through ngCordova. I saw few questions in the web like mine, but didn't found any solution, so maybe somebody can help me with this.

```
10-14 20:29:51.202 4552-4552/? I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(26794)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
                                           at Object.Plugin.share (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-instagram-plugin/www/CDVInstagramPlugin.js:93:18)
                                           at Object.share (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/libs/ng-cordova.js:4805:17)
                                           at file:///android_asset/www/scripts/controllers/homeCtrl.js:206:31
                                           at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56230:19
                                           at Object.ionic.Platform.ready (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2140:9)
                                           at Object.self.ready (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56223:26)
                                           at home.shareInstagram (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/controllers/homeCtrl.js:205:26)
                                           at Object.$ionicPopup.show.buttons.onTap (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/controllers/homeCtrl.js:170:105)
                                           at Scope.extend.$buttonTapped (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:56771:45)
                                           at fn (eval at <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27638:15), <anonymous>:4:386)", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (26794)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, maybe to somebody it will help. In description of cordova instagram plugin there is written that i should pass two parameters like this

```
share(imageData, imageCaption)
```

but it is an error, because it should be passed as **object** of parameters, instead of two values:

```
 $cordovaInstagram.share({image: image.data, caption: image.caption}).then(function() {
          // Worked
          alert('instagram sharing worked');
        }, function(err) {
          // Didn't work
          alert('instagram error');
        });
```